# Installing Postgres Client alone without server

Tags: postgresql

Here is my requirement.

Server 1(DB)

Server 2(ETL)-Need to install pg_client alone, where I can fetch and load data in Server 1 using pg_bulkload.

Is there is any way to do it? Kindly provide instructions, to install the client and where I can get the software package.

Thanks

Comment: Here you go - https://www.pgadmin.org/

Comment: Each operating system/distribution handles this in a different way. Please give us more information on what environment you work in.

Comment: He spoke about a server ("server 2"), I doubt he wants a graphical interface ...

Comment: AFAIK, pgAdmin should works with Win/Linux/Mac, We can wait for OP's reply though

Comment: Thank you. Both servers were Redhat Linux. One server is ETL server and another is DB server. Need to do operation like select and loading should be through pg_bulkload in ETL server.

Comment: Thanks Fabian.GUI is not required.

Comment: My question was not clear. So I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

When building from Source you can do after `configure` and `make`:

> Client-only installation: If you want to install only the client
>   applications and interface libraries, then you can use these commands:

```
make -C src/bin install
make -C src/include install
make -C src/interfaces install
make -C doc install
```

> src/bin has a few binaries for server-only use, but they are small.

[Link to PostgreSQL Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/install-procedure.html)

Comment: Thanks Ben. We will try that.